# distcp causing skewness in HDFS

Tags: hdfs, distcp

I have a folder(around 2 TB in size) in HDFS, which was created using `save` method from Apache Spark. It is almost evenly distributed across nodes (I checked this using `hdfs fsck`).

When I try to `distcp` this folder (intra-cluster), and run `hdfs fsck` on the destination folder, it turns out to be highly skewed, that is, few nodes have a lot of blocks whereas few nodes have very less blocks stored on them. This skewness on HDFS is causing performance issues.

We tried moving the data using `mv` from source to destination (intra-cluster), and this time the skewness in the destination was fine, that is, the data was evenly distributed.

Is there any way to reduce the skewness in HDFS when using `distcp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of mappers in the `distcp` were equal to the number of nodes which were heavily loaded.

So I increased the number of mappers in `distcp` using the `-m` option to the number of machines present in the cluster, and the output was much lesser skewed.

An added benefit: the `distcp` job completed much quicker than what it used to take earlier.